# Toggling Mac audio playback

Tags: macos, cocoa, audio, key, toggle

I'd like to programmatically pause/resume the currently playing audio on my Mac just like the F8 button on Apple keyboards does. It occurs to me that the affected application (e.g. iTunes and/or Spotify) is the one running in the foreground (whatever the definition of that is). How can I achieve this (more elegantly than by just emulating this particular keystroke)?